# jQuery hasClass and if

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a problem with jquery hasClass.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var body = $('body'),
    leftPane = $('.pane-left');

leftPane.on('click', function () {

    body.removeClass('left-closed');
    body.addClass('left-open');
    $('.pane-left h2').fadeIn(600);

    setTimeout(function() {
        rightPane.fadeOut(0);
        $('.pane-left-wrap').fadeIn(100);
        $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:first-child').fadeIn(100);
        $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(2)').fadeIn(600);
        $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(3)').fadeIn(1200);
        $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(4)').fadeIn(1800);
        $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(5)').fadeIn(2400);
    }, 600);

});

if(body.hasClass('left-open')) {

    leftPane.on('click', function () {

        body.removeClass('left-open');
        body.addClass('left-closed');
        $('.pane-left h2').fadeOut(600);

    });

}

});
```

I click pane-left and left-open is added to my body tag. Then i click again but the code inside my if() is unreachable. Why is that?

Comment: Your `if` condition is only executed on page load, not after your click adds the class `left-open`.

Comment: Instead of conditionally binding, check for the state inside the binding to know if you should perform the logic or not.  OR if possible change it to be a delegate binding that will include the conditional check as part of the child selector.

Comment: The `if` for hasClass should be inside of your click handler which means you would have one click handler and check for your class inside of it

Comment: you can't do this, you should add the event listener then on click check for the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If condition only run once in `document.ready` state, so you must be add if in your `click` event. But you have a action in `click` event and i think it's correct code for your purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var body = $('body'),
        leftPane = $('.pane-left');

    leftPane.on('click', function () {

        if(body.hasClass('left-open')) {
            body.removeClass('left-open');
            body.addClass('left-closed');
            $('.pane-left h2').fadeOut(600);
        } else {
            body.removeClass('left-closed');
            body.addClass('left-open');
            $('.pane-left h2').fadeIn(600);

            setTimeout(function() {
                rightPane.fadeOut(0);
                $('.pane-left-wrap').fadeIn(100);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:first-child').fadeIn(100);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(2)').fadeIn(600);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(3)').fadeIn(1200);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(4)').fadeIn(1800);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(5)').fadeIn(2400);
            }, 600);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the check for `.left-open` into the click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = $('body'),
    leftPane = $('.pane-left');

    leftPane.on('click', function () {

        // Added for check 'left-open' class.
        if(!body.hasClass('left-open')) {
            body.removeClass('left-closed');
            body.addClass('left-open');
            $('.pane-left h2').fadeIn(600);

            setTimeout(function() {
                rightPane.fadeOut(0);
                $('.pane-left-wrap').fadeIn(100);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:first-child').fadeIn(100);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(2)').fadeIn(600);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(3)').fadeIn(1200);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(4)').fadeIn(1800);
                $('.pane-left-wrap .secondary-nav li:nth-child(5)').fadeIn(2400);
            }, 600);
        }

        // Moved this function inside click event.
        if(body.hasClass('left-open')) {
            leftPane.on('click', function () {
                body.removeClass('left-open');
                body.addClass('left-closed');
                $('.pane-left h2').fadeOut(600);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if you already use bad formatting at least explain what you changed in the code.

Comment: Added comments wherever necessary. Sorry for the inconvience.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what your looking for *(cleaned up version)* and [.toggleClass();](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) seems more suitable for your scenario.

```
if ($('body').hasClass("left-open")) {
    $('#leftPaneElem').click(function() {

         body.toggleClass('left-closed');

          // more stuff

    });
}
```